# Determine what objects depend on a sequence?

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to `DROP SEQUENCE` on sequence that should not exist in my table. [The documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-dropsequence.html) is clear that if the `CASCADE` option is used, objects that depend on that sequence will be dropped. How do you determine what objects those might be (if they exist)?

Specifically, before running this in a production database I need to verify that nothing critical will be deleted.

I can determine **if** a sequence has been used:

```
dev=> SELECT sequence_name, last_value FROM mytable_columnname_seq;

sequence_name          | last_value 
-----------------------+------------
mytable_columnname_seq |          2
(1 row)
```

In the above we see that the `last_value` is `2`, which means it has been used. But it doesn't indicate by *what*.

Resolution (and thanks to a_horse_with_no_name and kiln; I couldn't accept both answers, which is a shame):

The 'dependent' object is the table's default value for the column the sequence is assigned to. If it is safe to remove the default value of the column, it is similarly safe to remove the sequence: no rows or tables will be deleted, and their values will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a sequence is [`owned by`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) a column, like in this case:

```
create table example_table (id serial);
```

You can use [`pg_depend`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-depend.html) to determine table name from sequence name:

```
select refobjid::regclass as table_name
from pg_depend
where objid = 'example_table_id_seq'::regclass
and deptype = 'a';

  table_name   
---------------
 example_table
(1 row)
```

Comment: Is this to say that only the table in question is a 'dependent object'? And that if it is, the table will be deleted if `CASCADE` is used? That doesn't sound quite right?

Comment: The table won't be deleted. If the table (or the column) is deleted then the sequence will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
select n.nspname as table_schema, cl.relname as table_name
from pg_class s
  join pg_depend d on d.objid=s.oid and d.classid='pg_class'::regclass and d.refclassid='pg_class'::regclass
  join pg_class cl on cl.oid = d.refobjid 
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = cl.relnamespace
  join pg_attribute a on a.attrelid = cl.oid and a.attnum=d.refobjsubid
where s.relkind='S' 
  and d.deptype='a'  
  and n.nspname = 'schema of the sequence' 
  and s.relname = 'sequence name'
```

Comment: The result of this would be a `table_name`: is that to say that `CASCADE` will delete the table? (PostGres documentation is light on what it considers an 'object' to be in this case.)

Comment: @NathanielFord: no. `cascade` doesn't drop the table, only the association of the column with the sequence. So a "serial" column will become a "plain" integer column without a default.

Comment: Why provide the `RESTRICT` option, then? I must be missing some fundamental understanding there.

Comment: Maybe you do not want the column's default to be dropped? See here for the result of a `drop .. cascade`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a673e/2

Comment: `Restrict` means that you won't drop a sequence if it is owned by a column.

Comment: I see. So the values in the column (which in this case is a non-primary key) will be left alone, regardless?

Comment: If a sequence is dropped, all values of corresponding column remain unchanged, only `default` constraint is dropped.